# Issue tracking applications that subdivide issues into (sub)tasks?

Tags: issue-tracking

I am looking for an issue tracking application, which has two levels in its task hierarchy. This is because I find myself very often creating informal "TODO" lists within my issues. It seems to me that a FEATURE is usually bigger than a TASK - one feature usually requires several things to be done - e.g. "check if this sth will affect efficiency", "add the control in the GUI", "implement new extension to the core engine", "update documentation". Without stating all these sub-task, I find it impossible to estimate the time needed and the real complexity of the complete task.

I know I could create several issues, but it is often not feasible because these sub-tasks:

- are related to a single feature from the user's perspective,
- can be tested only together, when everything is done,
- have the same developer assigned-to,
- should be displayed together all the times,
- should have only two states: todo or done.

Do you know any (commercial or not) applications that allows this? I am not just interested in hierarchies of issues or issue linking, but I need something with full issues on one level and with smaller and quicker "todo" lists on another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Jira and Fogbugz have subtasks. I have found however no application, where subtasks were something smaller and quicker than tasks - I still have to repeat all the fields of the main task.

I ended up using Project Kaiser and I am satisfied with it. It has quite nice hierarchical subtasks.

Comment: Does this one or any one of products you reviewed allow you to create a template task where you can repeat a task and the sub-tasks over and over.  For example, we have a lot of websites that go from development to production, there are a lot of sub-tasks that have to happen to "take a site from dev to prod".

Answer (score 1):

I've used both Jira and TeamTrack in previous jobs, and they both have sub-tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

(*) FogBugz - fogbugz.com
"FogBugz allows you to create subcases to represent lower-level tasks."

(*) IssueTrak - issuetrak.com
Solid issue-tracking system that I can recommend.

(*) CounterSoft's Gemini - countersoft.com
Feature-rich, much like Jira. Looks very promising.

Look also for project management systems for developers - these systems handle "projects" with "tasks".

/Kristoffer  :-)

Comment: I can't see subtasks in IssueTrak and Gemini.

Comment: IssueTrak: Issues can have tasks ("sub-tasks").

In Gemini you create a project ("task") with related issuse ("sub-task").

Comment: Ok, IssueTrak has something I am looking for. Unfortunately my overall first impression about this system is that it is one of the worst I have seen.

Answer (score 1):

you could also use [mantis](http://www.mantisbt.org/):

- you can relate issues, including as sub-issues
- sub-issues can block a parent issue from being set to fixed until all sub-issues are fixed
- you could have feature/ parent issues in a separate project

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use [ToDoList](http://www.abstractspoon.com/tdl_resources.html) for my personal tasks list, since it is a very simple and focused tool.

I know it doesn't exactly fit what you're searching (one application that does everything), but I use it effectively in coordination with our *enterprise-grade* bug tracking system.